# File.list() returns files in a different order for 4.0 than 2.2

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-2.2-froyo, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

If i am using Android 2.2 and call `File.list()` method in [BookGenerator.java](http://code.google.com/p/seniordesignp8/source/browse/trunk/Project8/src/com/project8/main/BookGenerator.java), then pages and chapters come in exact sequence, but whenever I execute on Android 4.0 it gives me reverse pages list or reverse pages order.

Is there a compatibility issue between 2.2 and 4.0?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you've typed. Can you make it a bit more legible?

Comment: @JasonRobinson ya sure i do . Can u have look at it now

Comment: Still having a hard time. Are you saying in versions 2.2 and 2.3, some array comes in a particular sequence, then in 4.0 it comes in a reverse sequence?

Comment: I think I understand. The `list()` method returns your files in one order for 2.2 and 2.3, and in 4.0 it's reverse of what you get for 2.2 and 2.3. Is this correct?

Comment: @JasonRobinson ya u r rite ? any solution?

Comment: your question, as worded, but near impossible to understand, so I tried to clean it up and make it clear. Please review my edit and make sure I conveyed your question correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on listFiles() for an ordered list of the pages:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

"There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order;"

You have to create your own ordering system, based on file name or lastModified or file's size. You can either use a Comparator < File > or Comparator < String > for sorting the files in a SortedSet, or as mentionned earlier, create an own class for the items to sort that implements Comparable. I would suggest the first solution as it's a bit stupid to wrap the File or String class into an other one just for this functionality.

An example with a lot of memory overhead:

```
TreeSet<File> pages = new TreeSet<File>(new Comparator<File>(){
   public int compare(File first, File second) {
      return first.getName().compareTo(second.getName());
   }
});

for (File file : allFiles) {
   pages.add(file());
}

allFiles = pages.toArray();
```

If you want a more efficient one, you have to implement your own method for sorting an array in its place.

Answer (score 3):

The `list()` method does not guarantee any specific order for the items. The Android documentation lacks this point but the official [Java SE API javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) warns about it:

> There is *no guarantee* that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

You should sort the array with [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) before using it.

```
File fChapters = new File(internalStorage + bookName + "/Chapters");
// Obtain the chapters file names list (the files in the directory)
chapters = fChapters.list();
// Sort the file names according to default alphabetic ordering
Collections.sort(chapters)
// The chapters list is now sorted from A to Z
```

With the `sort(List list, Comparator c)` overload of this method you can define whatever order you need. For example, ignore the case of the letters in the titles:

```
Collections.sort(chapters, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String chapter1, String chapter2) {
        return chapter1.compareToIgnoreCase(chapter2);
    }
});
```

Comment: can u just write down the sort method u mentioned here , it will be more helpful to me .

Comment: Hi, in the example I took the snippet from your code. Just go ahead and remove the reverseArray() method, and substitute where it is called with Collections.sort(chapters). It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Comparable to sort it yourself.

Comment: Can u explain ur answer  more descriptive ?